# Bug when importing Neural Nets from .m files in a fresh kernel

Tags: bugs, warning-messages, neural-networks

**Bug introduced in 11.0.0 and fixed in 11.0.1**

---

Importing Neural Nets from .m files seems to destroy the neural net.

```
net = NetInitialize @ DotPlusLayer[3, "Input" -> 5];
Export["net.m", net]
```

`Import`ing the .m file right after exporting it does not have any issues. However, when you start a fresh kernel and `Import` it:

```
Import["net.m"]
```

There is the following error:

> `` TensorT::shdw: Symbol TensorT appears in multiple contexts {NeuralNetworks`,Global`}; definitions in context NeuralNetworks` may shadow or be shadowed by other definitions. ``

... and a nonfunctional neural net as the output.

To note, `TensorT` is not a global variable (running `?TensorT` in a new session gives a `Information::notfound` error).

`Import`ing the file again or running a random `` NeuralNetworks` `` code before `Import`ing solve the problem.

Comment: Did you report this to support?

Comment: @Szabolcs Not yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is related to [auto-loading of symbols](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AutomaticLoadingOfPackages.html).

It appears that now the `` NeuralNetworks` `` context is public.  However, it is not actually populated until some neural net function is used.  Observe:

[image]

I do wonder if all these symbols are actually meant to be in a public context ...

When you import `net.m` in a fresh kernel, the symbol `` NeuralNetworks`TensorT `` has not yet been created.  Thus when the kernel reads `TensorT` (without an explicitly specified context), it creates `` Global`TensorT `` and not `` NeuralNetworks`TensorT ``.  At the same time, `DotPlusLayer` is also read from `net.m`.  This triggers the loading of all the symbols in `` NeuralNetworks` ``, but not before `` Global`TensorT `` has been created.  So we end up with `TensorT` in the wrong context in your expression, and a symbol shadowing situation.

This smells like a bug to me.

The simplest workaround is to trigger loading of the neural net stuff by evaluating something like `DotPlusLayer` (with no arguments) right after kernel startup.

Another, more complicated workaround is the following:

In a fresh kernel, trigger loading of NN stuff:

```
In[1]:= DotPlusLayer;
```

Now remove `` NeuralNetworks` `` form the context path.

```
In[2]:= $ContextPath = DeleteCases[$ContextPath, "NeuralNetworks`"]
```

Export your expression only now:

```
net = NetInitialize@DotPlusLayer[3, "Input" -> 5];
ExportString[net, "Package"]

"(* Created with the Wolfram Language : www.wolfram.com *)
\
DotPlusLayer[<|\"Type\" -> \"DotPlus\", 
  \"Arrays\" -> <|\"Weights\" -> RawArray[\"Real32\", \
{{-0.5826271176338196, 
      0.7301018238067627, 0.6151853203773499, 0.7818413376808167, 
      -0.679416835308075}, {-0.03140471875667572, 0.6534066796302795, \

      -0.16610436141490936, 0.004304547794163227, 0.8150935173034668}, 
      {0.04995853826403618, -0.6442268490791321, 0.5564413070678711, 
      -0.22295577824115753, 0.6135303974151611}}], 
    \"Biases\" -> RawArray[\"Real32\", {0., 0., 0.}]|>, 
  \"Parameters\" -> <|\"Size\" -> 3, \"$InputSize\" -> 5|>, 
  \"Inputs\" -> <|\"Input\" -> NeuralNetworks`TensorT[1, {5}]|>, 
  \"Outputs\" -> <|\"Output\" -> NeuralNetworks`TensorT[1, {3}]|>|>]
"
```

Notice that now the context is prepended to `TensorT` upon export.

**To sum up, my suspicion is that the bug is that the `` NeuralNetworks` `` context is made public.**  It shouldn't be in the context path at all.  If it is in the context path on purpose (not as an oversight), then symbols such as `TensorT` should exist already on kernel startup (perhaps as a [`Stub`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Stub.html)).

Comment: Correct, this is a bug. It's a quirk in PacletManager that I can work around. Fixed, will be corrected in 11.0.1.